# How to customize sudo permissions when using OS Login?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) is enabled, and a user is granted access by having either the "Compute OS Login" or "Compute OS Admin Login" roles, they can run sudo.

In my experience, the per-user sudoers file always has this permission:

```
# cat /var/google-sudoers.d/first_last_example_com 
first_last_example_com ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Is it possible to customize these permissions or even disable sudo completely for a specific user or group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user with the role `roles/compute.osLogin` should be able to login but should not be able to run `sudo`.

The role `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` is required to login and use `sudo`.

Double-check the IAM roles you have assigned to users.

There are roles that include `roles/compute.osAdminLogin`, so you might be granting admin rights without realizing it. If the user has the primitive `roles/owner` or `roles/admin` role, or if they have `roles/compute.instanceAdmin`, these roles already include instance access roles with administrator permissions.

Google Compute Engine supports startup scripts  [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux). You can remove users in the `google-sudoers` group by adding the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo deluser USERNAME google-sudoers
```